# TFS Build Server won't deploy my .pdbs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs, msbuild

The steps of my build:

- NuGet Installer - get all packages for all solutions in the source tree
- Visual Studio Build - Build the solution - no special parameters
- Visual Studio Test - Run tests on built solution
- Visual Studio Build - Publish specific website - MSBuild Arguments = `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Publish /p:OutputPath=Publish /p:TeamDirectory="$(TeamName)\\" /p:ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol=false`
- Publish Build Artifacts

Additional configuration:

- Going to properties for the website in VS, all build configurations have "Exclude generated debug symbols" unchecked.  This is reflected in the .csproj file with `<ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>false</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>` under each PropertyGroup.
- Going to properties for the website in VS, under Build -> Advanced, all build configurations have Debug Info = pdb-only (except Debug, which has full).  This is reflected in the .csproj file with `<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>` and `<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>`

The bin directory for all projects including the website contains appropriate .pdb files.  The Publish directory and the generated artifact do not have any .pdb files except for `Antlr3.Runtime.pdb`, `EntityFramework.MappingAPI.pdb`, and `RefactorThis.GraphDiff.pdb`.  Running publish locally through VS copies the .pdb files as expected.

Comment: I tested at my side, TFS has the same behavior with local VS. Normally the `Antlr3.Runtime.pdb` and project `project.pdb` will display there, If you have other third packages, you need to make sure the `.pdb` files are included in them when get sources. Whatever, have a try for these arguments `/p:DebugSymbols=true /p:DebugType=full`

Comment: Hey, that did it!  Please make that an answer.  In your comment, did you mean that you tested it and found the same problem?

Comment: @Andy-MSFT See above

Comment: Yes I tested and have the same problem with you. I have posted the comments as answer below.

Comment: Hi There, I tried the same options but still am not able to publish the .PDB files of project referenced DLL's and my issue is bit different, I can able to publish the ,PDB files from Visula Studio (right click on website and publish) but am not able to publish PDB files by using command line and TFS vNext build (Visual studio 2017.3 and TFS 2018.3). Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested at my side, TFS has the same behavior with local VS, it's the default behavior.

Normally the `Antlr3.Runtime.pdb` and project `project.pdb` will display there, If you have other third packages, you need to make sure the `.pdb` files are included in them when get sources.

Whatever, have a try for these arguments `/p:DebugSymbols=true /p:DebugType=full`